# Nexus: Link to latest release of an artifact

Tags: url, maven, nexus

How to create a link to get the latest release of an artifact?
E.g. `org.foo:bar` would have 1.0 and 2.0, and the link would return the 2.0 release;
and when 3.0 is released and deployed, the same link would return the 3.0 release, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use "LATEST" but if you want the latest release, you can ask with the "RELEASE" keyword:

```
http://somerepo.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=groupId&a=artifactId&v=RELEASE
```

This will get you the latest given release, not just "LATEST" which will give you the last thing built (last thing uploaded for that group+artifact combo).

Answer (score 0):

I have found about this kind of query:

`http://somerepo.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=groupId&a=artifactId&v=LATEST`

But at the same time, a discouraging text explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280447/how-do-i-provide-url-access-to-the-latest-snapshot-of-an-artifact-in-nexus

So while this may work to some extent, it's not something really supported by Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

In nexus 3, according to [official manual](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset)

You can download the archive by search download API:

```
http://${nexus host}/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository={repoName}&group={group}&name=core&maven.baseVersion=x.x.x-SNAPSHOT&sort=version&direction=desc&maven.extension=jar
```

It will automatically sort by version field and fetch the latest one

The inner API list you can find in `Manage UI > System > API`, it is written by swagger